# Tonecheck for Twitter and Facebook?

Tags: email, social-networking

There's a plug-in for Outlook that checks emails for language that could potentially make someone feel negative emotions called [ToneCheck](http://www.tonecheck.com/demo), and I was wondering if there was any similar software for Twitter, Facebook, bookmarklet, or webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently @lymbix has only built a plugin for Outlook - but.. not to dispare because there is an API which means developers can actually build their own tools and publish them! see http://www.toneapi.com

Comment: Thanks Josh :) Maybe I can be the one to start working on the bookmarklet then...I signed up for the API.